# Python GIL with Threadpool

Tags: python, gil

I have a sample code, to demonstrate python GIL, and the relevant output.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time
from itertools import repeat
from time import sleep

values = [3,4,5,6]
def cube(x, y):
    print(f'Cube of {x}:{x*x*x}')
    c = []
    for i in range(0, 100000):
        c.append(i)
        d = len(c)
        e = c.index(i)
    return x*x*x

y = {3: 3}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rres = []
    ss = time.time()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        rres= executor.map(cube,values, repeat(y))

    print(rres)
    for ij in rres:
        print(ij)    
    print(f"Time taken is {time.time() - ss}")
```

And the output is:

```
Cube of 3:27
Cube of 4:64Cube of 5:125Cube of 6:216


<generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at 0x1103b0f20>
27
64
125
216
Time taken is 234.87321090698242
```

The timing part of the output is expected, due to python GIL, only one thread is using the CPU at a time, but what I fail to understand is that these lines:

```
Cube of 3:27
Cube of 4:64Cube of 5:125Cube of 6:216
```

These appeared simultaneously. I epected these to come in intervals of 60 sec, like sequential counterpart of the code. Can anyone explain this part to me? TIA.

Comment: Might be line buffering. Try to run with `python -u`!

Comment: The GIL prevents threads from running concurrently on multiple CPUs, but it does not prevent them from being switched.  Each one will run for a certain number of ms in round robin fashion, so they will finish at about the same time.